# PHP Goutte. Change Select Field and capture Ajax Changes - Scraping BigCommerce

Tags: php, ajax, screen-scraping, bigcommerce, goutte

I am currently scraping a website running BigCommerce.

The variations have dropdown boxes, when the end user changes one of the select boxs the product information changes, the URL doesn't change.

When the select box is changed it POSTS the product ID and Variant ID, the page is then updated.

How can I mimic this select box change? I have tried to replicate the POST but I get a security token error as I suspect it's blocking cross domain scripting.

The page URL doesn't update so I can't even loop through pages, the form code is here

```
<div class="productView-options-wrap" data-product-option-change="" style="">
    <div class="productView-options-inner">
        <div class="form-field" data-product-attribute="set-select">
            <label class="form-label form-label--alternate form-label--inlineSmall" for="attribute_select_176">
                Color: <small>Required</small>
            </label>

            <select class="form-select form-select--small" name="attribute[176]" id="attribute_select_176" required="">
                <option value="">View Options</option>
                <option data-product-attribute-value="1126" value="1126">1 Standard (Most Popular)</option>
                <option data-product-attribute-value="1127" value="1127">1 Standard</option>
            </select>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>


    <div class="form-field form-field--increments">
        <label class="form-label form-label--alternate" for="qty[]">
            Quantity:
        </label>
        <div class="form-increment" data-quantity-change="">
            <input class="form-input form-input--incrementTotal" id="qty[]" name="qty[]" type="tel" value="1" data-quantity-min="1" data-quantity-max="0" min="1" pattern="[0-9]*" aria-live="polite">
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="form-action">
    <input id="form-action-addToCart" data-wait-message="Adding to cart…" class="button button--primary" type="submit" value="Add to Cart">
</div>
```

The ajax being called is

```
   var formData = {
  "action": "add",
  "attribute[176]": "1130",
  "product_id": "931",
  "qty[]": "1"
};
$.post('https://example.com/remote/v1/product-attributes/931', formData)
  .done (showResult)
  .fail(showError);
```

Thanks

Comment: Annoyingly I can use Guzzle, send the Ajax and receive the information back. Trying to make the same call using Goutte fails with the security token. I am setting the headers and passing the cookies.

Such a simple thing and yet driving me nuts

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways you can go about doing this.

You can use the V3 API, fetch all of the products, including their variants. You can use that data to hit the Product/Variant Options Endpoint, where you'll be able to read all the options metadata. You will be able to manually re-construct the HTML that way - although it's really not ideal.

An alternative would be to determine the SKU of each product variant, and append that as a query parameter to the product page URL.

If you include the SKU as a query parameter to the product page, it will render out the pre-selected option configurations.

I'm a bit confused as to what you're trying to accomplish with the scraped data? If you're going to be performing actions on it, you'll likely run into further CORS issues.

Comment: It's a suppliers website, they have 100+ SKU's and each of the SKUs has variants. They don't have the information in a CSV/Excel sheet and don't want to give API access as they have a lot of data that isn't public.

I used ParseHub to scrape the data but it's limited without paying and I can't warrant $150 a month.

I can scrape a single page and glee all the data but it's the variants I am struggling with.

I can't use the GET as I don't have the SKU's without first changing the select box.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up re-writing this using use Symfony DomCrawler and Guzzle

I was able to save the security token and submit with the ajax call and process the data that way. 700+ products in around 10 minutes.